# How to implement Gover's algorithm with unknown number of solutions using qiskit or pennylane?

Tags: grovers-algorithm

In general Grover's algorithm has a fixed number of solutions. But in special cases, we can't know the exact number of solutions, even the solutions change over time. So how to construct oracle in this case? Specifically, I need to implement the Grover's algorithm  with unknown solutions using qiskit or pennylane.

Comment: Related for general rather than platform-specific: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/13318/what-to-do-when-the-amount-of-solutions-is-not-known-before-applying-grovers-alg