How many times do I have to repeat the oracle + amplitude amplification in Grover's algorithm?
My question is: How many times do I have to repeat the oracle + amplitude amplification in Grover's algorithm?
For further info: I am using 13 qubits and the # of solution states is unknown (may have 0, 1, 2, etc - based on dataset)

Edited for more clarity

See this https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/13318/what-to-do-when-the-amount-of-solutions-is-not-known-before-applying-grovers-alg
